# Load page with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

If you see Twitter following and followers users pages you can see this thing:

there's two tabs called "Following" and "Following" like this: [ Following | Followers ]

If you click `Following`, the page loads the following users page, if you click `Followers` the page loads the followers users page.

When you click `Following` the URL become **http://example.org/#!/following** and when you click `Followers` the URL become **http://example.org/#!/followers**.

I want something like this, how can I implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: Be wary of creating URLs that use hashbangs; these break if JS fails to load (e.g., because of a slow mobile network) or run (e.g., because of developer error). The History API is a useful, proven substitute, as explained by [Kyle Neath](http://warpspire.com/talks/responsive/) and [Dan Webb](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many plugins for jQuery that implement this, and I figure also for other frameworks.

See:
http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/#